# Can't set 1280x1024 on Ubuntu with Nvidia Geforce 8400 GS

Tags: resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-9.04

> **FINAL UPDATE:** [Here is the best solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th) that I found after going through this problem lots of times. The question below is outdated because as it turns out the computer is not the problem; the monitor is the problem.

Ubuntu doesn't offer 1280x1024 but that's what my monitor has
--> I want to set that resolution but need help doing so.

Ubuntu offers 1360x768, 1152x864, 1024x768 when using the Nvidia driver version 180. This is Ubuntu 9.04 installed as "Wubi" through Windows, I believe it's the amd64 version.

Google gave me [this precise explanation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) which is complete latin to me; I'm a Windows guy and not familiar with Terminal. [These SU questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=ubuntu+nvidia+1280) also don't provide answers, hence this new question. I hope you can help, and I will provide additional info if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why detecting monitor matters: In Ubuntu, the default set in /etc/X11/xorg.conf for the supported refresh rates of the monitor are extremely conservative. This is because some CRT monitors could stop working if you set refresh rates too high.

The solution with an undetected monitor is usually this:
1- Find somewhere the actual supported refresh rates for your monitor
(for example you can find from that page: http://www0.shopping.com/xPF-BenQ-BenQ-19-LCD-T905-TCO99-Monitor-Silver-Black-12ms that the vertical range is 56-76 and the horizontal range is 31-81).
2- Edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file in section "Monitor" to use those ranges:
 `Section "Monitor"

        Identifier     "Monitor0"

        VendorName     "Unknown"

        ModelName      "CRT-0"

        HorizSync       31.0 - 81.0

        VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0

   EndSection`
3- Restart X or your computer
4- Run nvidia-settings and the resolution you're looking for should be there.

Comment: Yay, this provided the desired resolution! Oddly, the refresh rate is 50 Hz and 52 Hz is also available, but neither 60 Hz nor higher is available. It works fine, though!

Comment: Restart X with the command `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `nvidia-settings` and check the tab that's labeled "X Server Display Configuration". Is the driver correctly detecting your monitor? If not, are you able to select the correct resolution on that screen?

Comment: The monitor model is "CRT-0", not "Benq T905" - so I'd say _no my monitor is not recognized_. This is where the above mentioned resolutions are listed, but not the one I need. How can I get it to detect my specific monitor? I expect that would then allow me to select the correct resolution?